# Binding Dependency Property to Current DataContext Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

I keep trying to make this hurdle in WPF, and I think I've found a solution, albeit an ugly one.

The scenario is as follows:

- I have a custom user control with a custom dependency property.
- The user controls can be nested inside of my other user controls.
- Each of my user controls has a data context that is specified by a locator (I am following the MVVM pattern)
- I want to bind the custom dependency property to a value in the parent view model.

Code...

**Parent View**

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ParentControlLocator}">

    <my:Child Demo="{Binding Path=DataContext.DemoTextAlpha, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}}" />

</UserControl>
```

**Parent Class View Model**

```
public class ParentClassViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _demoTextAlpha = "Some Alpha text";

    public string DemoTextAlpha
    {
        get
        {
            return this._demoTextAlpha;
        }
        set
        {
            this._demoTextAlpha = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("DemoTextAlpha");
        }
    }
}
```

**Child View**

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ChildControlLocator}">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" />

</UserControl>
```

**Child View Code Behind**

```
public partial class Child : UserControl
{
    public Child()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DemoProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Demo", 
                                       typeof(string), 
                                       typeof(Child),
                                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
                                       {
                                           PropertyChangedCallback = OnDemoChanged,
                                           BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
                                       });

    public string Demo
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(DemoProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(DemoProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnDemoChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (Child)d;
        var viewModel = (ChildViewModel)control.DataContext;

        viewModel.SomeProperty = (string)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

**Child View Model**

```
public class ChildViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _someProperty;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _someProperty; 
        }
        set
        {
            _someProperty = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("SomeProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, so this **WORKS**. What I'm trying to achieve is better/ more elegant code, particularly as it regards to this statement.

```
<my:Child Demo="{Binding Path=DataContext.DemoTextAlpha, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
```

Even that I could live with, as far as elegance goes, but one thing that is bothering me right now is that when I type

```
Path=DataContext.DemoTextAlpha
```

The intellisense drops when I try to drill down inside the DataContext. So I have to be extra careful to type everything right.

So - is there any different way to make the properties of the DataContext appear in intellisense, or is there an alternative way to achieve the same thing that I'm doing now?

Thanks.

**EDIT to Clarify**

When I put something like this instead of specifying the relative source as in the above examples...

```
<my:Child Demo="{Binding DemoTextAlpha}"/>
```

I receive an error...

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DemoTextAlpha' property not found on 'object' ''ChildViewModel' (HashCode=34126977)'. BindingExpression:Path=DemoTextAlpha; DataItem='ChildViewModel' (HashCode=34126977); target element is 'Child' (Name=''); target property is 'Demo' (type 'String')
```

Answer (score 5):

The `DataContext` (along with a lot of other properties such as `FontSize`) is ["Inherited"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx) along the visual tree. Therefore this:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ParentControlLocator}">
    <my:Child Demo="{Binding Path=DataContext.DemoTextAlpha, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
</UserControl>
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ParentControlLocator}">
    <my:Child Demo="{Binding DemoTextAlpha}"/>
</UserControl>
```

---

With regards to the Intellisense support, I don't know what VS version you're using, but I'm using VS 2010 Pro with ReSharper 6.1 and it adds Intellisense support if you specify the `d:DataContext` value:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...etc."
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheViewModelNamespace"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}">
```

**Edit:**

Ok.. let's analize what you're doing here:

**1** - Binding the UserControl to the ParentVM:

```
ParentVM -> UserControl
```

**2** - Using RelativeSource To Grab some property from ParentVM and place it into a Custom DP you created in the Child control

```
    ParentVM -> UserControl -> Child Control
```

**3** - In the OnPropertyChanged of the custom DP, setting that same value to the ChildVM

```
    ParentVM -> UserControl -> Child Control -> ChildVM
```

Do you realize you're using the View (User Control, Child Control) as an intermediate to share some properties between 2 View Models? Why don't you just

```
    ParentVM -> ChildVM
```

Which would be easier, cleaner and really MVVM?

Either put a reference from the ParentVM directly to the ChildVM, or use something like a `Messenger` pattern to have indirect communication between them.

Comment: Please check my edit to the OP to see my clarification... I tried to put it in a comment but I couldn't format it properly.

Comment: Drat! Another thing I left out.

What you have said is something I have been doing for a while. I had references to the other VMs in the constructor and when I needed to populate the data, I just did it that way. 

However, I encountered this problem when I need to place 2x of the ChildControl within the same parent. Does that make sense?

Comment: +1, because you reminded me of the fact that there is absolutely no need to bind a dependency property to the DataContext. You just saved me a lot of work and maintainability issues.

Answer (score 1):

DataContext is inherited:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ParentControlLocator}">

    <my:Child Demo="{Binding DemoTextAlpha}" />

</UserControl>
```

If, ina different scenario, your child control has a different DataContext specified and you still need to bind to a property of your parent control's `DataContext`, using `ElementName` is probably nicer:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Parent" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ParentControlLocator}">

    <my:Child Demo="{Binding Path=DataContext.DemoTextAlpha, ElementName=Parent}" />

</UserControl>
```